# Usage description for NSCameraUsageDescription

Tags: ios, permissions, app-store

Is a formal description of using permission enough to approve an app in the Add Store?

For example, is this option suitable:

```
This app requires access to the camera
```

... or should it be specified as follows:

```
This app requires access to the camera to take a picture for the profile or scan a QR code
```

It is rather difficult to describe in detail what this permission will be used for. For example, the camera can be used for many functions (take a picture, read a QR, record a video). At the same time, I would not want the app to be rejected due to the lack of a detailed description.

Comment: I don't work for Apple, but if all you say is *"This app requires access to the camera"* it will almost **certainly** get rejected. Apple doesn't seem to mind verbose, so ***"This app uses the camera for various functions, including taking Profile Pictures, Scanning QR Codes, recording videos, etc"*** would probably suffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, they will not reject you if you keep your message like the first option. But what is written in the documentation of Apple about this is:

> For each key, provide a message that explains to the user why your app
>   needs to capture media, so that the user can feel confident granting
>   permission to your app.

This message will be shown to the user and do you think the user will be happy with your explanation of why you need the camera permission.

> This app requires access to the camera.

If this is not a well-known app I will reject this permission.

Much better is if you show something like this:

> This app requires access to the camera to take a picture for the
>   profile or scan a QR code when you need it.

At the end of the day, you deciding how to build trust in your users.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Apple reviewer's mood...
My app passed with a usage description similar to your first option, but later it was rejected, so go with the specified version.

[image]